# unknown ca in erlang log

Tags: erlang, ssl-certificate, cowboy

I am creating  Erlang servers with 3 files: `cowbow-ca.crt`, which is I guess is the certificate of the CA, and `server.key` with `server.crt`, but I see this error message in my log.

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Feb-2016::13:00:13 ===
Error in process <0.31594.15> on node 'node1@web02.example.lab' with exit value:
{closed,[{ranch_ssl,accept_ack,2,
                    [{file,"/www/web/staging/postman.example.lab/deps/ranch/src/ranch_ssl.erl"},
                     {line,115}]},
         {cowboy_protocol,init,4,
                          [{file,"/www/web/staging/postman.example.lab/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl"},
                           {line,91}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Feb-2016::13:00:13 ===
Ranch listener https had connection process started with cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at <0.31594.15> exit with reason: {closed,[{ranch_ssl,accept_ack,2,[{file,"/www/web/staging/postman.example.lab/deps/ranch/src/ranch_ssl.erl"},{line,115}]},{cowboy_protocol,init,4,[{file,"/www/web/staging/postman.example.lab/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl"},{line,91}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Feb-2016::13:00:18 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:93:Fatal error: unknown ca

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Feb-2016::13:01:11 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:93:Fatal error: unknown ca

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Feb-2016::13:01:18 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:93:Fatal error: unknown ca
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fatal error in `ssl_alert.erl:93` means that this is an alert that was received over the TLS connection.  So this means that the client that's connecting to your server doesn't recognise the CA that issued the certificate.  You could avoid this by adding the CA certificate to the client's list of trusted certificate issuers.

Comment: is there a way to get the ip address of that client?

Comment: I don't know much about Cowboy or Ranch, but one of them should be able to log such failures along with IP addresses. Failing that, you could capture the traffic with Wireshark and see which connection is getting terminated.

Comment: there is no IP address of the client in the log, I am not sure that it will drop the TCP session immediately

Comment: I'm getting this error on my server which is being connected to by other phoenix / elixir systems. How could I adjust them to work?